# llvm optimizations

Tags: c, optimization, llvm

[List of available LLVM passes are desribed here](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html). I am interested in knowing which passes are included for different optimization levels. For example, for -O2 which passes are included. Is there any site or document which provides that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's visible in [PassManagerBuilder.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp) file. Take a look at populateModulePassManager method where OptLevel is integer that follows -O option.

Answer (score 1):

from the command line you can use:

```
echo "" | opt -O3 -disable-output -debug-pass=Arguments
```